# Input type password breaks layout in Chrome and Opera

Tags: css, google-chrome, layout, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

There is a odd thing when using `input type password` in a client's layout. On Chrome and Opera on Mac it totally breaks my layout. When I change to `input type email` the layout is fine. In all other browsers it works as expected.

I already checked my site on validator.w3.org, unfortunately there was no error such as not closing element or anything else :(

To see the input field you have to click on "*login*" in the black top navbar.

[click here to see it in action](http://andalusi.com/development/)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is appear in chrome because you are using `float` property on `p` element which is inside `header` element and you are not clearing floating.

Check the Below HTML Code and use `overflow:hidden` on class `page-header`  .

```
<header class="page-header">
<a title="Zur Homepage" href="index.html">Maximilian.it</a>
<p>Passion for fashion</p>
</header>
```

Check the CSS Code.

```
.page-header {
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
border-bottom: none;
overflow: hidden; /*Added New line*/
}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Lets try to put `position:relative` on class `.page-header` and then give `position:absolute` to `p tag.`

```
.page-header {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: none;
    position: relative; /*Added New line*/
    }

.page-header p
{
float: right !important; /*Remove this line*/
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 35px;
}
```

Comment: I added `overflow: hidden` to `class="page-header"` but it is even worst.

Comment: I don`t even know why this is happen only when I write `input field password`.

Comment: let me share my chrome screenshot here. You can see the webInspector here.

Comment: I of course believe you :-) But I updated the link an it is even worst.

Comment: Try to add `margin:0` on `.page-header p` lets see what happened.

Comment: Negative! The thing is, when I change the input type it works. This is probably the strangest bug I ever heard about it.

Comment: hmm strangest issues.

Comment: Have you tested it on windows PC. In my windows chrome browser showing it fine.

Comment: Yes, I tested it on Chrome/Win8 and Opera/Win8 via VMWare. Same issues there. Firefox and even IE looks like expected.

Comment: I found a solution ..lets try this

Comment: check my Updated answer please and lets try this new method. let me know if it works.

Comment: Its actually a whole workaround but its now fine for me. [link](http://andalusi.com/development/)

Comment: yep you can say workaround, but if its suits you, you can accept the answer.